# The API request failed with the following error: 200 - OK

Tags: api, browser, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I administer my shared hosting through cPanel.

It is showing "The API request failed with the following error: 200 - OK." **in red popup**.

Everything is working fine. I can work on everything as usual, but still this pop?

**When i login from another browser, the error is not shown.**

How to get rid of it and why is this being shown?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather, it is about an error in cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get rid of this message was my question.

I had installed a chrom plugin that allowed me to use CORS.

After uninstalling this plugin, the error was gone.